# Efficient Python lib to query the RUNNING state of given network interface on Linux?

Tags: linux-networking, interface

I want to monitor the RUNNING state of a certain network interface in an efficient way, without constantly calling `ifconfig` every second, or so, and parsing its output. So I'm asking if someone knows a way to efficiently get this state information in Python on Linux.

I know of `netifaces`, but it doesn't give me interface states. So I don't know if the interface is just available, or really online/running.

Then I looked into `psutil`, but if I'd not missed something there, it has no access to this kind of network interface state either. If I'm wrong, I will be happy to get corrected and get specific info on how to achieve my goal.

Comment: You should take a look in `/sys/net/<interface>/`.  `carrier` and `operstate` are places you can start.

Comment: @yoonix is there a way to avoid constantly opening, reading, then closing the /sys/net pseudo files?

Comment: If you want to read updates, no.  How else are you going to read the contents?  What's the problem with opening reading and closing?  This is what the /sys filesystem is for.

Comment: I was afraid that this causes much higher load than a dedicated socket call I may have overlooked.

Comment: @yoonix repeated open/close isn't necessary, a seek works like a charm, and I get fresh state information on each seek()/read().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that reading `/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier` works quite well and efficiently. In particular, it isn't necessary to constantly run the `open()`/`readline()`/`close()` sequence, as this is much less efficient than to simply `open()` only once and then repeatedly do `seek(0)` followed by `readline()`.

This all even works across pulling and hot-plugging the network interface.

A `flush()` isn't necessary and won't do anything anyway in this case, as the `open(...,'r')` is read-only and `flush()` is a no-op in this mode, per the official Python documentation.